# pass parameter from coordinator.xml to workflow.xml oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a requirement that, I need to take the date from coordinator to workflow in oozie.

For that I have developed sample coordinator and work flowas following. But, after launching coordinator job, all workflow jobs are failing with error code E0701. Means xml parsing error. I tried very hardly, where I am doing wrong? I couldn't find out the issue? please help.

**workflow.xml**

```
<workflow-app name="test_wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="samp_pig"/>
    <action name="samp_pig">
        <fs>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <delete path='${nameNode}/tmp/${wf.conf("DATE")}'/>
        </fs>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error      message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]    
</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

**coordinator.xml**

```
<coordinator-app name="test"
  frequency="5"
  start="2014-07-15T11:35Z" end="2014-07-17T12:15Z" timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
  xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${wf_application_path}</app-path>
      <configuration> 
    <property>
        <name>DATE</name>
        <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}</value>
    </property>
      </configuration>
   </workflow>
  </action>
```

**job.properties**

```
jobTracker=localhost.localdomain:8021
nameNode=hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
oozie.coord.application.path=/tmp/uc1/
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
wf_application_path=/tmp/uc1/wf1/
```

**commands using**

```
hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/uc1/
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/uc1/wf1/
hadoop fs -put * /tmp/uc1/wf1/
hadoop fs -put * /tmp/uc1/
oozie job -oozie  http://localhost.localdomain:11000/oozie -config job.properties -submit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. We should not use

```
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
```

inside "fs" action.
Remaining everything as is. Even coordinator working fine.

Answer (score 1):

To get value of DATE property in coordinator.xml, just use `${DATE}`

> ```
>     <fs>
>         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
>         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
>         <delete path='${nameNode}/tmp/${DATE}'/>
>     </fs>
> ```

Comment: Tanks for the help. I did as mentioned above. still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Additional observation - Even When you try to use WF EL Functions - Correct way is **wf:** not **wf.**